# Is there any such example?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am looking for an example that $H,K,L$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $HKL$ is a group but prodoct of any two is not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$G=S_3\;,\;\;H=\langle\, (12)\,\rangle\;,\;\;K=\langle\,(23)\,\rangle\;,\;\;L=\langle\,(13)\,\rangle$$

Comment: I could not guess that it was so easy, thanks.

Comment: @mesel, that is why it is worthwhile to check the easiest cases first...and only thereafter to mess with tougher ones.

Comment: you are right !